# Mac Finder change sort order of files beginning with numbers

Tags: mac, finder

Is it somehow possible to change the sort order of those files in Finder from:

```
200803-somename.pdf
200805-somename.pdf
200910-somename.pdf
20080401-somename.pdf
20080402-somename.pdf
```

to

```
200803-somename.pdf
20080401-somename.pdf
20080402-somename.pdf
200805-somename.pdf
200910-somename.pdf
```

So that they are sorted alphabetically instead of numerically first? (MacOS Catalina)

Comment: Not according to documentation - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/309888/115093

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change this, you must change your date input.

You need to use consistent date formats - 20080101 up to 20081231 for instance. Each number is the same length, sorted YYYYMMDD. You can hyphenate etc if you wish, but you must maintain the YYYY-MM-DD format [single century would allow for YYMMDD, e.g. if no dates are 1999 or earlier]

macOS [& also Windows in recent years] uses [natural sort order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order), as noted in comments above, on [Ask Different - Understanding 'sort by name' behavior in Finder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/309884/85275). You cannot change this.

As it stands 20080401 is a larger number than 200910 & therefore the sort is 'correct' [for a given definition of 'correct']. Finder does not recognise them as dates, merely numbers.

If you have no DD information, then use 00 as padding.